# Graphing a spiral

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program is made, so it graphs a spiral with N steps. 
What else could I add to this program?

**Can this code be improved?**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100
arr = [(0, 0)]
x = []
y = []

for u in range(1, N):

    for i in range(1, 5):
        if i % 4 == 1:                      # first corner
            arr.append((u, - u + 1))

        elif i % 4 == 2:                    # second corner (same positive numbers)
            arr.append((u, u))

        elif i % 4 == 3:                    # third corner (same [one positive and one negative] numbers)
            arr.append((-u, u))

        elif i % 4 == 0:                    # fourth corner (same negative numbers)
            arr.append((-u, -u))

print(arr)                                  # just to easily check all coordinates

for i in arr:
    x.append(i[0])
    y.append(i[1])


plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 12):

Your inside for loop is useless as it loops over 4 values ([1,2,3,4]) and you have 4 `if` insinde it. you could have:

```
N = 100
arr = [(0, 0)]

for u in range(1, N):
    # first corner
    arr.append((u, - u + 1))
    # second corner
    arr.append((u, u))
    # third corner
    arr.append((-u, u))
    # fourth corner
    arr.append((-u, -u))

# Transforms [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)...] in x = (x1, x2...) y = (y1, y2...)
x, y = zip(*arr)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Answer (score 10):

Instead of redundant traversal and `append` to multiple lists - use an efficient *generator* function with further [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) call to aggregate the needed **`x`**, **`y`** coords sequences:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def spiral_coords_gen(n=100):
    yield 0, 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        yield i, -i + 1
        yield i, i
        yield -i, i
        yield -i, -i


x, y = zip(*spiral_coords_gen())
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: hey, sorry for late response. I don't completely understand what does the "yield" function do in this case.

Comment: @urbanpečoler https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator

Answer (score 7):

Except for what @Cal wrote, you can get rid of the zipping as well:

```
N=100
x=[0]
y=[0]
for u in range(1, N):
    x += [u, u, -u, -u]
    y += [1-u, u, u, -u]

plt.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: Approaching code golf, but if N is fixed it could be written as ```N=100
x=[0]
y=[0, 0]
for u in range(1, N):
    x += [u, u, -u, -u]``` where `x` would also be `y`. The issue is that there is one too many elements at the end of `y`.

Comment: @alexyorke my solution puts stress on readability. Your solution is not at first glance obvious why that is the case. And unless the plot function can ignore the extra y coordinate, it is meaningless. And even if it could, it Is not very smart to rely on such behaviour.